# Como enumerar a posição de um bit dentro de um byte?

Tags: binary, byte

Por onde começar a  colocar um numeração ordinal em um dado byte , eu começo a contar do mais significativo (a esquerda )ou do menos significativo(a direita)?

Por exemplo para o numero decimal 128 que tem a represntação em binario:

```
1000 0000
```

Se  eu quiser me referir ao **oitavo** bit do byte, quem é o digito em questão?
1 ou 0 ?

Seria do modo A ou modo B?
Modo A
1000 0000
8765 4321

Modo B
1000 0000
1234 5678

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem o que deseja, se é algo conceitual, se é concreto. Concretamente é bem mais complicado que isso. Não sei se a pergunta não é ampla. Enumerar como? pela pergunta só posso presumir que é olhar aí e contar até 8 e pegar o dígito desejado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O modo **A** seria o correto.

Ignore o nome `bit` - Um valor em binário é representado da mesma maneira que um valor em decimal: Em um número inteiro as posições de maior valor se localizam à esquerda, já que novas posições são adicionadas quando a posição anterior sofre *overflow*:

```
    8 + 1  // 9:     Uma casa decimal
    9 + 1  // 10:    Não pode ser contido em apenas uma posição,
   10      //        casa decimal 2 recebe o valor em overflow.
  ...
   98 + 1  // 99:    Duas casas decimais
   99 + 1  // 100:   Não pode ser contido em apenas duas posições, 
  100      //        casa decimal 3 recebe o valor em overflow.
```

Assim:

```
128 = 100 + 20 + 8
```

No exemplo acima podemos dizer que a posição(casa) `3` possui o valor `1`, que significa `100` em decimal.

Em binário o valor

```
1000 0000
```

Possui o valor `1` na posição `8`, o que também significa 128 (2 à 7a potência).